# how to find best set of splitting points

Tags: algorithm, constraints, mathematical-optimization

I have a long sound file with pauses of varying lengths. How do I find the set of pauses that splits the sound file into segments so that each is 30-120 seconds in length and the shortest used pause is maximal?

Comment: `the shortest used pause is maximal` explain more!

Comment: The result is a set of pauses, each has a duration. So in the resulting set, one or more has minimal length. I want this minimal length to be as long as possible. In plain words: I want to split the file so that I avoid short pauses.

Comment: May be you can create a small data set and a solution so we can understand the problem a little bit better. E.g. what is happening with the pause at which you split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can find the pauses:

- Make a list of the (start time, duration) of all the pauses, sorted by start time
- For each pause, calculate the best result (max shortest pause length) for splitting the sound up to that point. For each pause, you can easily calculate this by considering the results you've already calculated for the pauses that happen between 30 and 120 seconds earlier.
- At the end, do a similar calculation by considering the pauses that happen between 30 and 120 seconds before the end to get the final solution.

Comment: After thinking a bit more, I don't think your approach can work. It is possible that you have to re-choose pauses up to the start when inspecting one deep into the file. https://s18.postimg.cc/tohmni70p/image.jpg

Comment: It works fine. If a pause is eventually chosen as a cut point, then there's certainly no harm if the selection of pauses that precede it is optimal, so no need to revisit the preceding choices.  Your way works too, though, and is easier to understand.  I like your way better unless you need to do this in a streaming manner.

Comment: I don't understand that there's no harm. If I select optimal cut points for a part of the file, it can force a worse global solution. Imagine a recording with a pause of length 0.4 at position 118 and 0.5 at position 120. This repeats every 120 seconds with 0.4 at 238 and 0.5 at 240, 10 times in a row. Then at position 1228 there is a pause of length 0.5 and after it only ones up to 0.2. I must revisit to the first cut point to avoid the 0.2 pauses.

Comment: For each pause, you select the optimal set of cuts for the part of the file that *ends and that pause*, probably just by linking it to the last pause in that set.  The set of pauses for the whole file isn't selected until you get to the end and pick the last pause.  In your example, all the repeating 0.4 and 0.5 pauses point back to the preceding 0.5 pause, except the first that point back to nothing.   At the end of the file, you select the last 0.5 pause which points back to the preceding 0.4 pause, which point back through all the other 0.5s

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution: sort the pauses by length, iterate from shortest to longest. If all intervals have already desired length, break. If the pause at hand can be deleted and all conditions are still met, delete it.

Comment: This approach also is flawed. If there are many equal-sized pauses, it is unclear how to choose the right one  among them.